# ng-repeat oddness, not returning the value of {{c.symbol}}

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm doing a:

```
<li ng-repeat="c in currencyList"><a ng-click="setCurrency('{{c.symbol}}');"><strong>{{c.symbol}}</strong> <small>{{c.name}}</small></a></li>
```

All the menu items look OK, but when I make the selection the `setCurrency` call fails. It sets `{{c.symbol}}` not the value of `c.symbol`.

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kq9joJ?p=preview) - Change the currency type.

Comment: simply remove the {{}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an updated version that works

```
<li ng-repeat="c in currencyList"><a ng-click="setCurrency(c.symbol);"><strong>{{c.symbol}}</strong> <small>{{c.name}}</small></a></li>
```